# Are software recommendation for data science on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

E.g.:

> I am looking for a program that would allow me to fine-tune pre-trained word embeddings on my data set.

Is that kind of questions be on-topic here or should it be rather posted on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tough one, since I can imagine questions that overlap both SEs.

Obviously, it would need to concern software relevant to statistics, visualization, ML to qualify here.

Within that domain, sometimes questions really mean an approach, algorithm or technique -- that seems better here than `softwarerecs`. Asking for a library is less clear, but still feels more in the spirit of this SE. I personally wouldn't migrate those.

Asking for a software product could go either way, to me.